# JQuery animate only one cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning JQuery and was wondering how you can only affect one cell from a table? 
This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/amosangyongjian/mmqasf5t/4/

This is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".expand").slideDown("slow");
  },function(){
    $(this).siblings(".expand").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

I've tried several other methods but none seem to work.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Try change `.siblings` to `.find`

Comment: Oh it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("td").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".expand").slideDown("slow");
   },function(){
    $(this).find(".expand").slideUp("slow");
   });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding:10px;
}

.expand {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tableclass">
<tr>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello1</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello2</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello3</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello4</p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete the queue of actions? If i hover each 10 times very fast and i move my cursor somwhere else, they will do it over and over again until the queue is over.

Comment: Yeah, you could save the state like here: https://jsfiddle.net/a1npjqLx/ I added a data-tag for setting some custom state, which is set by begin and after the slide has finished.

Answer (score 1):

`td` doesn't have any siblings with `.expand`. However, `p` does.

So you have two alternatives, either set the event listener to `td p`, which also would affect the area that you can hover. So what you really want is probably to change:

`$(this).siblings(".expand")`

to

```
$(this).children(".expand")
```

```js
$("td").hover(function(){
  $(this).children(".expand").slideDown("slow");
}, function(){
  $(this).children(".expand").slideUp("slow");
});
```

```css
td {
  padding:10px;
}

.expand {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tableclass">
<tr>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello1</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello2</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello3</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p class="expand">Hello1Expanded</p>
    <p>Hello4</p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, i prefer using the .find one as the area of it is much larger. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I figured. In this scenario `find` and `children` would return the same result, but I personally prefer `chilren` if you know the structure since it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
    this is correct way when you choose via $("td")

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("td").hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".expand").slideDown('slow');
          },function(){
            $(this).find(".expand").slideUp("slow");
          });
        });

or

 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("td").hover(function(){
            $(this).children(".expand").slideDown('slow');
          },function(){
            $(this).children(".expand").slideUp("slow");
          });
        });

    your code also work when you change your code $("td p")

     $("td p") -siblings will  .expand
     $("td") -siblings will another td datas

    because siblings will it get previous element.
```